# Split an integer into the sum of four even positive integers that add up?

Tags: python

I was asked to write a Python program in which:

- We will enter the positive integer N
- Then we will count how many ways to decompose the positive integer N into the sum of **exactly 4 positive even integers.**

Example for easy visualization: If we have **N = 10**, we will have **4 ways** of splitting:

```
10 = 2 + 2 + 2 + 4
10 = 2 + 2 + 4 + 2
10 = 2 + 4 + 2 + 2
10 = 4 + 2 + 2 + 2
```

I wrote this program:

```
import os
import sys

def count_way_decompose(n: int):
    count: int = 0

    for a in range(2, n - 5 + 1, 2):
        for b in range(2, n - a - 3 + 1, 2):
            for c in range(2, n - a - b - 1 + 1, 2):
                d = n - a - b - c

                if d >= 2 and d % 2 == 0:
                    count += 1

    print(f"We have {count} ways to decompose {n} into sum of four even positive integers")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Code goes here
    n = int(input("N = "))
    count_way_decompose(n)
```

It uses brute-force and has a time complexity of **O(N^3)** because it goes through nested loops to find those 4 even positive integers.

And when I run with positive integers **N >= 1000**, my program slows down noticeably and peaks at **N = 10000**, my program takes up to 6 minutes to complete and CPU is always at 70% for this program

I know this is not a good way. But I can't think of any other solution. I tried swapping the loop positions, but it gave me the wrong results, and I can't use that approach.

So, is there a better and faster approach to doing this? Or will I have to keep using brute-force because there is no other way?

Comment: You should check out dynamic programming, i.e. once you have calculated possible ways to make up 4 out of 2 even numbers, you don't have to re-calculate that for the prefixes 2+4 and 4+2.

Comment: @tobias_k Thank you for your help, but the problem is asking me to calculate the permutations as well, like the example N = 10 above, 2 + 2 + 2 + 4, we can move the number 4 from end to top, forming 4 ways. So the final number of results will include the permutation of a way of adding integers. For example N = 10 we have 4 ways (including permutations of one) and for N = 1000 we have 124250 ways, and N = 2000, we have 165668499 ways (including permutations taste of a way)

Comment: @duckk404 tobias is saying you can break up your logic into smaller chunks. 4 is always 2+2, so you don't need to recalculate that multiple times.

Comment: You can return an answer in O(1), but dynamic programming is certainly a good way of proving that fact.

Comment: you may go even further. take in consideration, that 2 is your smallest number, your atom, so to say...

**Example:** N = 10. list = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10].
`10 doesnt work, because 10 + 2 + 2 + 2 > 10`
`8 does not either, because: 8 + 2 + 2 + 2 > 10`
`6 does not either, because: 6 + 2 + 2 + 2 > 10`
`4 does work, because: 4 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 10 (this solution has multiple permutations)`
`2 is already included in 4`
(Sorry for the weird formatation. You cant have newlines in comments...)

Comment: The biggest time sink here is actually defining *combinations* of 4-element tuples for large values of *n*.  Even a range of `2...20` has 9 even digits and 126 possible combinations of those digits. As your maximum number gets larger, so does your count of arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final O(1) solution: (n-1)(n-2)(n-3)/6, where n = N/2.

Proof (by quasi-dynamic programming):

Firstly, discard cases where N is odd or < 8.

Otherwise, set n=N/2. Then we want 4 positive integers (even or odd) that add up to n.

Let C(x,j) be the count of the ways that j positive numbers add up to x. We want C(n,4).

Work down:

C(n,4) = sum from i=3 to n-1 of C(i,3)

C(i,3) = sum from j=2 to n-1 of C(j,2)

But C(j,2)=j-1 (you can just list them).

So, working back up by doing the sums:

C(i,3) = (i-2)(i-1)/2

C(n,4) = (n-1)(n-2)(n-3)/6

(Remember, after all that, that n = N/2. I've called it this in the program below).

```
def count_way_decompose( N ):
    if N % 2 == 1 or N < 8: return 0
    n = N // 2
    return ( n - 1 ) * ( n - 2 ) * ( n - 3 ) // 6

N = int( input( "Enter N: " ) )
print( count_way_decompose( N ) )
```

Output:

```
Enter N: 10000
20808342499
```

Comment: Very nice. Not sure I grasp all of that (long day...) but the result matches up.

Comment: I'm not mistaken, is C(i, j) a union?

Comment: @duckk404, C(i,j) is just "dynamic-programming-type" notation that I created for this problem. I was going to do it by dynamic programming ... and then suddenly realised that you could do the sums explicitly. To be fair to tobias_k, I did cross-check my answer against his solution for a lot of values of N.

Answer (score 1):

One way to speed this up is using dynamic programming, i.e. caching results of sub-problems that can be reused multiple times. Consider your triple-loop. There are different combinations for `a` and `b` such that `a+b` is the same value, yet you execute the inner-most loop for all those combinations.

In order to detect and avoid those redundant calculations, you can restate your problem to the more general "split integer into sum of k even integers", make that a recursive function, and cache the results. You can very easily cache many Python functions (with hashable parameters and immutable results) using [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache).

Here's an example:

```
from functools import cache

@cache
def count_way_decompose(n: int, k: int) -> int:
    if n % 2 != 0: return 0
    if n < k * 2: return 0
    if k == 1: return 1
    return sum(count_way_decompose(n-i, k-1) for i in range(2, n+1, 2))
```

This could be optimized a lot more, by restricting the upper limit of the loop depending on `k` etc., but even in this form this calculates `count_way_decompose(2000, 4)` in well under half a second on my system, or 5 seconds for `n=10000`.

Or closer to your original code, just manually caching the inner-most loop, with similar performance:

```
def count_way_decompose(n: int) -> int:
    count_ab = {}
    count: int = 0
    for a in range(2, n - 5 + 1, 2):
        for b in range(2, n - a - 3 + 1, 2):
            if a+b not in count_ab:
                count_ab[a+b] = 0
                for c in range(2, n - a - b - 1 + 1, 2):
                    d = n - a - b - c
                    if d >= 2 and d % 2 == 0:
                        count_ab[a+b] += 1
            count += count_ab[a+b]
    return count
```